# How do i design a Paint Application like MS Paint using JAVA OOps and design Principles?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have been asked to design a Paint Application in JAVA .It is just a implementation problem not a original Paint GUI where we can draw.

Requirements:

1.It should have a File Menu : which would have 3 options :
a. A New File
b. Save the file
c. Open the file which we last saved

2.It should support drawing 3 Shapes
a. Circle
b. Rectangle
c. Line

3.We can color the shapes

So I created a Interface called "Shape" inside which I have two method signatures

1.draw();
2.color(String color);

Then i created 3 classes "Circle", "Line" and "Rectangle" and implemented the "Shape" Interfaces and gave method definition to draw() and color() in all the three classes.

Something like this:

```
   public class Line implements Shape {

        @Override
        public String draw() {
            return "Line is drawn";
        }
        @Override
        public String color(String color) {
            return "Color of line is "+color;
        }
    }
```

I have also created a Paint Class which would be my main class or object of this class would be the new Paint Canvas.

I have made it something like this till now

```
public class Paint {

    List<Shape> shapes;
    public Paint(){
        shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    //to draw a line call Line Class
    public Line drawLine(){
        return new Line();
    }

}
```

But now I am confused how do I implement the features
1.Open a New Paint File
2.Save the Paint File
3.Open the file we have saved.

How do i implement all these features just by using plain Java ? Or which Data Structure shall I use for this. Can someone please help me design this ?

[![Image of my project structure]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dk3Qn.png)